# SCCM Cross Forest SUP

Tags: wsus, sccm-2012-r2

I have a site with an existing SUP server (fully working, set to ports 80/443, though SSL is not configured) and am adding a SUP in a new untrusted forest.  The WSUS component is configured (80/443) and can reach and sync from the upstream SUP and this server is already successfully configured as an MP/DP.  However, when the Site Server attempts to manage/configure the SUP role I get a weird error (though the SUP role did install successfully):

```
    Using NEWFOREST\SCCMAccount credentials for network connections SMS_WSUS_CONFIGURATION_MANAGER  7/26/2016 1:07:57 PM    8780 (0x224C)
    Attempting connection to WSUS server: NEWSUP.NEWFOREST.COM, port: 80, useSSL: False SMS_WSUS_CONFIGURATION_MANAGER  7/26/2016 1:07:57 PM    8780 (0x224C)
    System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.~~   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy.CreateUpdateServer(Object[] args)~~   at Microsoft.SystemsManagementServer.WSUS.WSUSServer.ConnectToWSUSServer(String ServerName, Boolean UseSSL, Int32 PortNumber)    SMS_WSUS_CONFIGURATION_MANAGER  7/26/2016 1:08:15 PM    8780 (0x224C)
    Done using NEWFOREST.COM\SCCMAccount credentials    SMS_WSUS_CONFIGURATION_MANAGER  7/26/2016 1:08:15 PM    8780 (0x224C)
```

Ports 80/443/445 are bidirectionally open and available and the site server can navigate to the IIS default site on the new SUP server, but I'm kinda stumped what could be causing the hang up here.  Any ideas?
Running SCCM 1606, both servers are 2012R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick turned out to be that though port 80 was open, the SOAP protocol traffic was still being dropped.  A new firewall rule later and configuration is successful.  Wanted to post an answer in case anyone comes across this later.